# Scribing a cicrular line in Canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am attempting to mouse-drag a dot around the outer perimeter of a large circle and have that dot appear to scribe a thick line around the outer perimeter behind itself. I can get everything to work except scribing the outer line behind the dot. I have researched many ideas and tried many of my own but the line still produces "spotted" results. Here is an image to show what I'm attempting.
[MounseDrag Scribed Line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MsXgI.jpg)
Thank you for taking the time to read my question. :-)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var canvas1 = document.getElementById("canvas1"),
      canvas2 = document.getElementById("canvas2"),
      c1 = canvas1.getContext("2d"),
      c2 = canvas2.getContext("2d"),
      dot = 7,
      started = false,
      width = 350,
      height = 350,
      radians = 0,
      cRad = 165, // Circle Radius
      cord = {mX:0, mY:0, csX:0, snY:0, x:0, y:0},
      init = function(){
        cord.mX = 0;
        cord.mY = 0;
        cord.csX = width /2 + cRad;
        cord.snY = height /2;
        cord.x = width /2;
        cord.y = height /2;
      };

  init();
  canvas1.width = width;
  canvas1.height = height;
  canvas2.width = width;
  canvas2.height = height;
  canvas1.addEventListener("mousemove", function(event) {
    cord.mX = event.clientX - canvas1.offsetLeft;
    cord.mY = event.clientY - canvas1.offsetTop;
  });

  canvas1.addEventListener("mousedown", function(event) {
    if (started) {
      started = false;
    } else {
      started = true;
      render();
    };
  });

  function update() {
    radians = Math.atan2(cord.mY - width/2, cord.mX - height/2);
    cord.csX = width/2 - Math.cos(radians) * cRad * -1;
    cord.snY = height/2 - Math.sin(radians) * cRad * -1;
  };

  function outerTheta() {
    c2.beginPath();
    c2.arc(cord.csX, cord.snY, 3, 0, Math.PI * 2);
    c2.closePath();
    c2.fillStyle = "#000";
    c2.fill();
  };

  function render() {
    c1.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
    c1.beginPath();
    c1.moveTo(cord.x, cord.y);
    c1.lineTo(cord.csX, cord.snY);
    c1.lineWidth = 3;
    c1.strokeStyle = "#000";
    c1.stroke();

    c1.beginPath();  //<---------------------------------- Drag-Dot
    c1.arc(cord.csX, cord.snY, dot, 0, Math.PI * 2);
    c1.closePath();
    c1.fillStyle = "#000";
    c1.fill();

    if(started){
      update();
      outerTheta();
      requestAnimationFrame(render);
    };
  };
  render();
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

The browser is not able to cycle the animation as quickly as the mouse is moving. If you move the mouse slowly, then the dots that are drawn in each animation cycle overlap and the circle has a solid line. If you move the mouse quickly, then the dots do not overlap and you get "spotting".

If you pay close attention to the way drawing programs work, you will see that the "pen" tool draws a continuous line. If you move the mouse quickly while using the tool, the continuous line is made up of line segments that stretch from each point that the computer was able to capture while your mouse was moving quickly.

I modified your program so that a line segment stretches between each captured point during the animation cycle:

https://jsfiddle.net/17hvw5pp

```
var canvas1 = document.getElementById("canvas1"),
      canvas2 = document.getElementById("canvas2"),            
      c1 = canvas1.getContext("2d"),
      c2 = canvas2.getContext("2d"),
      dot = 7,
      started = false,
      width = 350,
      height = 350,
      radians = 0,
      cRad = 165, // Circle Radius
      cord = {mX:0, mY:0, csX:0, snY:0, x:0, y:0},
      init = function(){
        cord.mX = 0;
        cord.mY = 0;
        cord.csX = width /2 + cRad;
        cord.snY = height /2;
        cord.lastCSX = cord.csX;
        cord.lastSNY = cord.snY;
        cord.x = width /2;
        cord.y = height /2;        
      };

  canvas1.style.position="absolute";
  canvas2.style.position="absolute";

  init();
  canvas1.width = width;
  canvas1.height = height;
  canvas2.width = width;
  canvas2.height = height;
  canvas1.addEventListener("mousemove", function(event) {
    cord.mX = event.clientX - canvas1.offsetLeft;
    cord.mY = event.clientY - canvas1.offsetTop;
  });

  canvas1.addEventListener("mousedown", function(event) {
    if (started) {
      started = false;
    } else {
      started = true;
      render();
    };
  });

  function update() {
    radians = Math.atan2(cord.mY - width/2, cord.mX - height/2);    
    cord.csX = width/2 - Math.cos(radians) * cRad * -1;
    cord.snY = height/2 - Math.sin(radians) * cRad * -1;
  };

  function outerTheta() {
    //draw a line from the last known coordinate to the new known coordinate
    c2.beginPath();
    c2.moveTo(cord.lastCSX, cord.lastSNY);
    c2.lineTo(cord.csX, cord.snY);
    c2.lineWidth=5;
    c2.strokeStyle="#000";
    c2.stroke();
    cord.lastCSX = cord.csX;
    cord.lastSNY = cord.snY;

    c2.beginPath();
    c2.arc(cord.csX, cord.snY, 3, 0, Math.PI * 2);
    c2.closePath();
    c2.fillStyle = "#000";
    c2.fill();
  };

  function render() {
    c1.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
    c1.beginPath();
    c1.moveTo(cord.x, cord.y);
    c1.lineTo(cord.csX, cord.snY);
    c1.lineWidth = 3;
    c1.strokeStyle = "#000";
    c1.stroke();

    c1.beginPath();  //<---------------------------------- Drag-Dot
    c1.arc(cord.csX, cord.snY, dot, 0, Math.PI * 2);
    c1.closePath();
    c1.fillStyle = "#000";
    c1.fill();

    if(started){
      update();
      outerTheta();
      requestAnimationFrame(render);
    };
  };
  render();
```

This works better, but not perfectly: If you move the mouse quickly, the line segment will become a chord across the circle and this ruins the effect.

I attempted to modify the program to draw an arc between the two known points:

https://jsfiddle.net/17hvw5pp/1/

You can see that this implementation is also not ideal because the arc function becomes confused about which direction to draw the partial circle based on just two radians coordinates. Using quaternion math will solve this problem for you.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternion

But that may be more complication that you want to introduce into this project.

Comment: For demos, please use Stackoverflow's internal [Snippets](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) rather than external Fiddles. :-)

Comment: I can't thank you enough for your time and help! The info. you provided has been very eye opening for me. I though I was missing something obvious. I can see the problem is actually pretty challenging to solve and this is going to be very helpful. I will work on it some more and see what I can do with it.  Thank you again Matt!